# Azure powershell command to get web app cpu & memory percentage

Tags: azure-app-service-plans

My requirement is to get the average cpu, memory percentage consumption for a web app hosted in azure. I would like to get the data using powershell command
So I tried the below command and received the below error, kindly help.

command 1:

```
Get-AzureRmAppServicePlanMetrics -ResourceGroupName 'RGname' -Name 'appserviceplan name' -StartTime ((get-date).AddHours(-1)) -Granularity PT1M -Metrics ["CPU Percentage"]
```

error:

```
Get-AzureRmAppServicePlanMetrics : $filter. Details: Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException: Syntax error at position 82 in 'name/value eq 
'CPU Percentage'and startTime eq '2018-12-19T13:52:33Zand' timeGrain eq 'duration''PT1M''''.
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.ExpressionLexer.ValidateToken(ExpressionTokenKind t)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.UriQueryExpressionParser.ParseFilter(String filter)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.ODataUriParser.ParseFilterImplementation(String filter, IEdmType elementType, IEdmEntitySet entitySet)
   at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.Csm.Common.ODataFilterParser.ParseMetricsFilterQuery(IEnumerable`1 queryNameValuePairs, String& 
   names, String& startTime, String& endTime, String& timeGrain). 
   name/value eq 'CPU Percentage'and startTime eq '2018-12-19T13:52:33Zand' timeGrain eq 'duration''PT1M''' is invalid.
   At line:1 char:1
   + Get-AzureRmAppServicePlanMetrics -ResourceGroupName 'resource group name ...
   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureRmAppServicePlanMetrics], CloudException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.WebApps.Cmdlets.WebApps.GetAzureAppServicePlanMetricsCmdlet
```

command 2:

```
Get-AzureRmAppServicePlanMetrics -ResourceGroupName 'RGname' -Name 'web app name' -StartTime ((get-date).AddHours(-1)) -Granularity PT1M -Metrics ["CPU Percentage"]
```

error:

```
Get-AzureRmAppServicePlanMetrics : Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'web app name' not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureRmAppServicePlanMetrics -ResourceGroupName 'resource group name...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureRmAppServicePlanMetrics], CloudException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.WebApps.Cmdlets.WebApps.GetAzureAppServicePlanMetricsCmdle
```

Please find my Powershell & AzureRM version details below

```
PS C:\Users\xxxx> Get-Module -Name AzureRM -ListAvailable
Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                     

---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                 

Script     6.13.1     AzureRM                                                                                                          

Script     5.4.1      AzureRM                                                                                                              

$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14409  1005
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just been running into the same problem, the commands Get-AzureRmAppServicePlanMetrics and Get-AzureRmWebAppMetrics don't appear to work currently, regardless of the options chosen.

Instead, I've been able to get the same data with the following command:

```
Get-AzureRmMetric
```

For example, to get the cpu usage and memory usage for the past 30 minutes, for 'webappname' in resource group 'rgname', with subscription id 'd6ae8085-3bbc-410e-8c95-7be4aa2adbeb', you would use the following:

```
Get-AzureRmMetric -ResourceId "/subscriptions/d6ae8085-3bbc-410e-8c95-7be4aa2adbeb/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/webappname" -TimeGrain 00:01:00 -StartTime ((get-date).AddMinutes(-30)) -EndTime (get-date) -MetricNames "AverageMemoryWorkingSet","CpuTime"
```

This will return an array with all of the metrics, with the data points in the 'Data' properties.

This command only seems to take a -ResourceId parameter, so I recommend using the 'Id' property from a Get-AzureRmWebApp result, as it'll be in the right format.

Hope that helps!